# Using EIGRP to Advertise a VPN Tunnel Route

Tags: networking, cisco, ios, eigrp

I have several routers all connected via a MPLS netowrk and one that is not.  The one that is not part of the MPLS network is connected to one that is via a VPN tunnel. All the routers on the MPLS network advertise their routes with EIGRP. Is there a way, without running EIGRP on the non MPLS router, to have the mpls rouyer that is the other end of the tunnel tell all the other MPLS routers about the network that the non MPLS router has?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a static route for the VPN-connected networks on the MPLS router which is the VPN endpoint and tell it to redistribute static routes via EIGRP - or if you don't want to redistribute all the static routes, add a "network" entry for the VPN connected network.

See: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk365/technologies_white_paper09186a0080094cb7.shtml#statictointerface

Comment: With the network entry, is the static route required?

Comment: Yep - the network entry just lets you redistribute single routes rather than all static routes configured on the router.

Answer (score 1):

You can put a static route on the MPLS router (that do the VPN tunnel) to the networks behind the non MPLS router then redistribute this static route in EIGRP.
You can filter redistributed static route with a route-map and an access-list.

the keyword to find documentation is "redistribute"